# variable must be absolutely global all over sources

Tags: c++, gcc, module, linker-errors

How do we make a variable global across over all .cpp files/modules of a (will-be) single binary, which is to be compiled and linked by g++ in a line?

even if it's been defined in main and has extern in var. to be included in every .cpp

```
extern int a_sample_var;
```

tried it for more a week only to fail,

> .....: undefined reference to `a_sample_var` .....

Any generous guru helping me out?

Comment: Global is a bad idea. Though you can introduce it to a namespace you use still not nice

Comment: Add it to a header and include it in all source files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files)

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
extern int a_sample_var;
```

Tells the compiler: there is a `int` named `a_simple_var` defined somewhere else (think about the keyword `extern`: it's abbreviation for `external`, meaning "somewhere else"). Just leave a placeholder there and wait for the linker to find it!

Well if you do this in every `cpp` file (by including a header), then everyone is crying for the definition (by providing a declaration), but with no one to provide the definition. **Be aware of the wording here, definition and declaration are different stuff**.

In exactly one `cpp` file, you shall provide a definition of `a_simple_var`. Just simply remove the `extern`:

```cpp
int a_sample_var;          // Initialize with 0
```

or

```cpp
int a_sample_var = 1;      // Initialize with 1.
```

Those two are proper definitions.

Comment: In my experience people complain about not explicitly writing `... = 0`, which is why I'd suggest `int a_sample_var = 0;` instead. But in a more open minded environment both might be ok.